# How to validate or invalidate this transaciton using Code?

Tags: transactions

Suppose I aim to validate this JSON file. How can I achieve this using Python programming?

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "e3b3ef1ee6b0f7d4b74b739b674278b0a9cb2d627a58e1168327046c497ed0f4",
      "vout": 0,
      "prevout": {
        "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
        "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
        "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
        "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
        "value": 179000
      },
      "scriptsig": "160014a5937228bff12b7da32fd34aa95a50d7d34785b4",
      "scriptsig_asm": "OP_PUSHBYTES_22 0014a5937228bff12b7da32fd34aa95a50d7d34785b4",
      "witness": [
        "304402204fb68257107f8058debbbbd17c9c4b9529eab28b8d0332ed2aa57419352b5600022027d8b84678f048b61337ec94520f84d7a09155d6f6764b5be0b5da61383d7b9801",
        "02016f521f750b1066923d9b8945079a3db30706b8fd792efe65081e08e086c550"
      ],
      "is_coinbase": false,
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "inner_redeemscript_asm": "OP_0 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 a5937228bff12b7da32fd34aa95a50d7d34785b4"
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 600
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f787",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 f5c1c5818535cb1a18902e3d05db9995c48097f7 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3Q6Tc2GDyHSkygUbzqqQ36jWwYmN59NN7S",
      "value": 165282
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your question was asked one minute apart from this one: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/122398/5406. Given the similar line of questioning and timing, I’m wondering, is this for a homework assignment?